# External commands not available in gvim on windows

Tags: windows, vim, windows-7, path

When starting a gvim session on windows 7, it appears that globally available commands like autopep8 or pylint cannot be executed. I.e. the command `:!pylint` opens up a console windows saying `'pylint' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

However, I can execute these commands from cmd.exe by just typing the respective names. 
This is because I have added the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\Scripts;` to the System Path environment variable. For some reason this is not picked up by the shell behind gvim.

The weird thing is that typing `:echo $PATH` shows a list or folders which includes `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\Scripts;`.
I should also note that this problem does not occur when starting normal vim in a terminal like cmd.exe or git bash.

Any hints on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Try `:!path` to see the actual path used by the spawned cmd.exe.

Comment: It prints `PATH=(null)`. For some reason there *is no path*? I find that very weird. Is it expected?

Comment: That would mean that _no_ external command (not even `hostname`) works, right?! Something must clear your path (i.e. `:set path=`). Can't imagine what; maybe check your Vim settings (`:set shell? shellcmdflag?` etc.) for strange stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Apparently I had a piece of vim script that modified the path and for some reason this does not work well with gvim. I should have thought of this... Commenting it out solves this issue. Will look into it.